# ActiveSupport::Concern vs append_features

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activesupport

There is [an article](http://opensoul.org/blog/archives/2011/02/07/concerning-activesupportconcern/) on `ActiveSupport::Concern` hooks. Here's a working implementation in Rails:

```
module ActionController
  class Base < Metal
    include AbstractController::Layouts
  end
end

module AbstractController
  module Layouts
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    include Rendering

    included do
      class_attribute :_layout, :_layout_conditions, :instance_accessor => false
      self._layout = nil
      self._layout_conditions = {}
      _write_layout_method
    end

    module ClassMethods
      ...
    end
  end
end

module AbstractController
  module Rendering
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      class_attribute :protected_instance_variables
      self.protected_instance_variables = []
    end

    module ClassMethods
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

How is the `extend` call in `Layouts` executed before the `append_features` ruby hook? The `extend` must be executed first. After all, the whole point of it is to hijack the `append_features` ruby default and reimplement it. However, according to Ruby documentation, `append_features` is executed right after you include this module (e.g. `AbstractController::Layouts`) in another (e.g. `ActionController::Base`). So there's confusion here for me. If that's the case, then the overwritten `append_features` of `ActiveSupport::Concern` will never be called.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take:

You can think of "include" like a method that takes a module as a parameter; in order to include a module, the module must already be loaded by the environment; otherwise the line would fail with a missing constant error.

Therefore, when `include AbstractController::Layouts` is called, Layouts must be loaded in the AbstractController or top-level namespace for this to work.

Peeking at the actionpack source code, it turns out that Layouts *is autoloaded*, which ensures that it will be loaded before the "include" line completes.

Since `extend ActiveSupport::Concern` is executed when Layouts is *loaded*, the `append_features` override *will be available* by the time "include" line in ActionController::Base has finished executing.

After this, the append_features method for Layouts will be executed with ActionController::Base as the argument.